# One word for person who work on two computers

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a funny word that corresponds to "[AMBIDEXTROUS](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=meaning%20of%20ambidextrous&oq=meaning%20of%20ambide&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.4639j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" (Person who can write equally well with either hand) in meaning but actually refers to the situation of a developer working on two PC simultaneously.

Is there any word out there yet?

Sample sentence:
That guy is seriously able to work and type simultaneously on both computers. He is "Techie-Ambidextrous" (< Need to replace this)

Comment: Except that the analogy doesn't work. People who are ambidextrous can write with either hand—but not with both at the same time. In general, anybody who does two or more things at once is a [multitasker](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multitasker). As far as I know, there is no word for a specific type of multitasking . . .

Comment: "Operator" comes to mind

Comment: It's normal in industrial applications for operators to work simultaneously on not two but sometimes several interfaces/ systems. Just for illustration: https://www.turbinetech.com/img/subpages/what-we-do/cmu/hmi-systems/Picture4.jpg

Comment: From the description of the single-word-requests tag: ***To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. ***  Please add such a sentence to your question.

Comment: Are you looking for a word that means working on two computers _simultaneously_ (as in one hand on each keyboard or something) or just having two systems running at the same time and switching back and forth between them (perhaps like this: http://sinasohn.net/junk/DSC_3271_sm.jpg)?  If the latter, I think @JasonBassford's suggestion of multi-tasker is a good one, although it's more about doing two (or more) tasks at once rather than specifically making use of two tools.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 6):

In the context of multiplayer gaming / MMORPGs, there's the term ["multi-boxing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-boxing), which seems to describe (albeit with a focus on a more specific niche) almost exactly what you're describing:

> **Multiboxing** refers to playing as multiple separate characters concurrently in an MMORPG. This can either be achieved by using multiple separate machines to run the game or by running multiple separate instances of the game.
>
> [...]
>
> Multiboxing may be as simple as running two instances of the game on one computer (each logged into a separate account) and switching between them. Players may also use multiple computers, each with their own keyboard and mouse. This quickly becomes impractical with an increasing number of computers, so a keyboard demultiplexer may be used, which sends the signals from a single keyboard to several computers or virtual machines on one computer.

The [Multiboxing FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20080829020511/www.vboxing.net/faq) (archived; original link is dead) further describes some specific variants on the terminology (like "2-boxing"/"dualboxing" or "5-boxing"/"quinboxing") and some of the technology used.

---

Another possibility, depending on the context, is to go for a pun, like "ambi*tech*strous".  Not strictly proper English, sure, but if it catches on, it's only a matter of time before it ends up in dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

You might call it *dual wielding*.

> **Dual wielding** is using two weapons, one in each hand, during combat.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_wield)

While this normally refers to weapons, with the right context it should be understood. Dual wielding is often used for humorous affect in action comedy movies so the connotation should carry over.

"Captain Linux over there is so serious he's dual-wielding keyboards and coding on 3 monitors."

Comment: It's a very niche use but I think it would work well in *some* contexts. The required level of nerdiness seems rather appropriate. Welcome